# IE10 DX Filter, css equivalent of addCone (or add circle)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

I'm not allowed to delete this question so just ignore it

In IE10, quirks mode, gradients now -ARE- appearing without my having to change anything. This is using the DXFilter, which I don't understand as the option is switched off and according to microsoft DXFilters now don't work in the internet zone?

---

(I missed out the 10 on IE10, question may make a little more sense now)

We have a site that is in IE6 quirks mode, it represents 10 years+ of development, has over 100 pages and realistically can't be changed without months of effort.

I need a css equivalent of gradients/addCone. At the moment I have a lot of info on the page, this cone appears in a tablecell, perhaps 20 of them. I looked at SVG but not sure thats a good fit as it seems quite verbose

Graphically I just want a gradient and a ball in the tablecell

It's arkward because if it was not in quirks mode we could use css3 but I don't think those features are available in quirks mode, but DX Filters have been taken away anyway

Any suggestions?

thanks

(addition, just found http://css3pie.com/ and a gradient of some description is appearing in quirks mode in IE10 so fingers crossed)

Comment: What does your existing code look like? Why is SVG not a good fit? Would CSS radial gradients be what you're looking for?

Comment: hang on... you're in quirks mode???? Oh dear, no wonder you're having trouble. Seriously, converting from quirks to standards mode is a lot easier than you'd think (`*{box-sizing:border-box;}` fixes most of the issues). And don't think you can keep ignoring the problem; if you stick in quirks mode you're going to keep getting issues like this, and they're going to get harder and harder to resolve the longer you leave them. IE11 is coming this year, and I'd be willing to bet IE12 next year.

Comment: A lot of our customers are on IE7 and will be for a good few years to come, at the moment we still have to support IE6 but that might come to an end soon. We are not in a position to dictate to our customers what browsers to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, heres what I found

- IE10 has withdrawn support for DXFilters, but you can put them back on in the browser. This can be set as a group policy

Internet Options-> Security-> Internet -> Custom Level -> Misc -> Enable Legacy Filters

- SVG doesn't work in quirks mode, even if it did it wouldn't help as I need a graphical effect in HTML but SVG in IE10 doesn't allow mixing (it does in other browsers)
- Gradients are in IE10, again don't work in quirks mode

css3pie implements gradients as (I think) VML, and it appears to work. The only thing you might have to tweak is to use position: relative in whatever container you're putting the CSS on